# Retrieve nested Cloud Firestore subcollections upon page load in Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm trying to create a simple blog example app in Angular using Google Cloud Firestore.

The data in Firestore is structured like this:

```
posts
    post1
        name: "Post about stuff"
        content: "This is a post about stuff."
        comments
            comment1
                title: "First"
                content: "I was the first to comment."
```

I'm trying to:

- retrieve a post and its comments upon page load
- display the post and its comments
- allow users to update the post and add comments to the post

The problem I'm running into is the comments aren't available until the post is returned from Firebase. My solution to that problem is mapping the getPost call to getComments so that once I get the post, the getComments call is made:

**post.service.ts**

```
export class PostService {
    postSelected$: Observable<Post>;
    // Keep comment collection around to easily get and add comments
    commentCollection$: Observable<AngularFirestoreCollection<Comment>>;
    postId = "0";

    constructor(private angularFirestore: AngularFirestore, private userService: UserService) {
        this.postSelected$ = this.getPost(userService.getUserId(), this.postId);
        this.commentCollection$ = this.postSelected$.pipe(map(post => {
            return this.getCommentCollection(userService.getUserId(), post.id);
        }));
    }

    getPost(userId: string, id: string): Observable<Post> {
        return this.angularFirestore.doc(`users/${userId}/posts/${id}`).valueChanges().pipe(map((firebasePost: any) => {
            return { id, ...firebasePost };
        }));
    }

    updatePost(postUpdate: {name?: string, content?: string}): void {
        /* update post */
    }

    getCommentCollection(userId: string, postId: string): AngularFirestoreCollection<Comment> {
        return this.angularFirestore.collection(`users/${userId}/posts/${postId}/comments`, ref => ref.orderBy("displayOrder", "asc"));
    }

    getComments(userId: string, postId: string): Observable<any> {
        const commentCollection = this.getCommentCollection(userId, postId);
        return this.getDocuments(commentCollection);
    }

    getDocuments(collection: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>): Observable<any> {
        return collection.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(snapshotChanges => {
            return snapshotChanges.map(snap => {
                const data = snap.payload.doc.data();
                const id = snap.payload.doc.id;
                return { id, ...data };
            });
        }));
    }

    addComment(comment: { title: string; content: string }): void {
        this.commentCollection$.pipe(map(commentCollection => {
            commentCollection.add(comment as any);
        }));
    }
}
```

**post.component.ts**

```
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {
    post$: Observable<Post>;
    commentCollection$: AngularFirestoreCollection<Comment>;
    comment$: Observable<Comment>;

    postNameControl: FormControl;
    postContentControl: FormControl;

    constructor(private userService: UserService, private postService: PostService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.postNameControl = new FormControl();
        this.postContentControl = new FormControl();

        this.post$ = this.postService.postSelected$;
        this.post$.subscribe((post: any) => {
            const { name, content } = post;

            this.postNameControl.setValue(name);
            this.postContentControl.setValue(content);
        });

        this.postNameControl.valueChanges.subscribe(name=> {
            this.postService.updatePost({ name });
        });

        this.postContentControl.valueChanges.subscribe(content => {
            this.postService.updatePost({ content });
        });
    }
}
```

The comments will have similar functions as the posts.

The problem is the addComment function doesn't work. My question is:

- Is there a better way to display a collection and its nested subcollection on page load?
- If not, why doesn't this seemingly simple addComment function work?

I've looked around quite a bit and haven't seen any documentation or tutorials on best practices for loading a collection and its subcollection on page load. Most of the AngularFire2 resources on the web only cover basic CRUD operations and the other stuff is usually out of date or using Firebase's realtime database.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How is the PostService hosted? Can you verify if the PostService Server process gets shut down at any point?  If so, commentCollection$: Observable<AngularFirestoreCollection<Comment>>; might not have the comments loaded anymore.

Comment: That would make sense but this problem happens even when hosted locally. These files are all part of the same Angular project.